# IEEEeqnarray: equation numbering on left side

Tags: equations

Is it possible to place equation numbers on the left side of the page in the environment IEEEeqnarray? Thank you.

So far I have been adding an extra column on the far left and manually adding equation numbers, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{-s"l}
    (1) & A \\
    (2) & A \to B \\
    (3) & B
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: All equation numbers, or some of them?

Comment: All equation numbers ideally.

Comment: I believe, reading the manual, that this option does not exist.